# pgr_nodeNetwork returns old_id as int and not bigint

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, routing

I am using `pgr_nodeNetwork('edges', 0.001, 'id', 'geom', 'noded', '',  f)` to create the paths network. Since the table is being re-generated multiple times the value of `old_id` in resulting table have cross integer limit and is giving error

```
Where: SQL statement "INSERT INTO public."edges_node_network" (old_id,sub_id,geom) ( WITH cut_locations AS
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: integer out of range
```

I am generating a new table as partition every time and later on attaching it to the parent table. I have changed the datatype of `old_id` as bigint in parent table but while generating new one it's giving integer out of range error.
How to solve this?

Also, how is this old_id generated, many times I have noticed it remains unchanged if we execute the `pgr_nodeNetwork` multiple times.